# Focus preventScroll not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, scroll, focus

I need to prevent the scroll caused by focus().
For this purpose, I found that if I use `element.focus({preventScroll : true})` instead of `element.focus()`, it works fine, based on the documentation from mozilla.
However, this only works perfectly on Chrome but not in Firefox.

I'm wondering how could it be not supported by FireFox, when the documentation has been done by Mozilla.
Am I missing something here?

[Focus method documentation by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)

Comment: Please note the documentation specifies the optional `focusOptions` parameter is considered **experimental** and should currently not be used in production code. I can confirm that the example Mozilla provides on the documentation page does **not** work on Firefox 60 (tested on 60.0.1 and 60.0.2).

Comment: hmm yeah...that says it all...but still surprising..as it works in Chrome! So, the only alternative I've currently is to reset the scroll behavior after on focus.

Comment: It's relatively new in Chrome as well. The `focusOptions` parameter has been [introduced with Chrome 64](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/nic64#more) this January.

Comment: Oh ok, but in my opinion, as seen in the past, firefox should have been the 1st browser to support this!